# Reading Unknown Number Of Lines In A File

Tags: vb.net, file, file-io

I have about 20 files, each file has a short description that starts on line 7 and goes to the 3rd to last line of the file.
For example, one file has the description started at line 7, and ends at line 10, but the file has a total of 13 lines.

How can I import JUST the description, for example line 7 - 10?
This is the example code I have so far.

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim MyDir As String = "..\GoodFils\"
    Dim MyFiles() As String = IO.Directory.GetFiles(MyDir)
    Dim Count As Integer = 0

    Public Function ReadLine(lineNumber As Integer, lines As List(Of String)) As String
        Return lines(lineNumber - 1)
    End Function

    Private Sub btnDo_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDo.Click
        Dim reader As New System.IO.StreamReader(MyDir & "gucci.hcs")
        Dim allLines As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim strTemp As String

        Do Until reader.EndOfStream = True
            allLines.Add(reader.ReadLine())
        Loop

        lblName.Text = ReadLine(2, allLines)
        lblPrice.Text = ReadLine(5, allLines)
        lblDesc.Text = EOF(1) - 3

        reader.Close()
        FileOpen(1, MyDir & "gucci.hcs", OpenMode.Input) 'May be able to use MyDir & lblName & ".hcs"

        For i = 7 To reader.EndOfStream
            Input(1, strTemp)
        Next

        lblDesc.Text += i
        FileClose(1)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Unless you have something as part of the file format to say how long it is, there's no way to tell a priori how many lines it is to get to 3rd last line.  You're reading all of the lines into a list, so just pull lines 7 to Count - 3 (check my math, might be off-by-one) out of the list.

Answer (score 1):

You can load the contents of each individual file into an Array by using [IO.File.ReadAllLines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalllines(v=vs.110).aspx) and then you can use LINQ to Skip to jump to line 7 and then Take up to the 3rd to last line.

Here is a quick example:

```
'Create a collection to store all of the file's descriptions
Dim descriptions As New List(Of String)

'Placeholder variable for the upcoming iteration
Dim lines() As String

'Iterate through each file
For Each file As IO.FileInfo In New IO.DirectoryInfo("GoodFils").GetFiles("*.txt")
    'Read the file
    lines = IO.File.ReadAllLines(file.FullName)

    'Get only lines 7 to n-3
    descriptions.Add(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, lines.Skip(6).Take(lines.Count - 10).ToArray()))
Next
```

Fiddle: [Live Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/zrYSkB)